# Silverlight web deploy dont change application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight-5.0, webdeploy

I have deployed ASP MVC  web application which hosts some silver light out of browser application. Client need to go to specific site and then install this app on their computer. Everything is working OK but i noticed that i have got old version of silver light app and each deploy don't change anything. Can anybody help with this issue?

Each deploy is via web deploy and deletes all files prior publishing but still silver light app don't change.

Comment: did you replace .xap file ?

Comment: yes i did. Now it is working on debug mode but on release it is still the same app